# Regular expression to match ASCII and Unicode letters

Tags: javascript, regex, character-properties

Recently I discovered, to my surprise, that JavaScript has no built-in support for Unicode regular expressions.

So how can I test a string for letters only, Unicode or ASCII?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd recommend Steven Levithan's excellent [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) library, which has a Unicode plugin containing various Unicode character classes: http://xregexp.com/plugins/

Comment: Hi there. I downloaded the library but I cannot get it to work. I am testing with the examples provided by the author but I don't get a match. Running unicodeWord.test("Русский"); (found on the author's site) returns false

Comment: @Thomas: it works perfectly for me: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/GAKYt/. Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 3):

> Recently I discovered, to my surprise, that javascript has no builtin support for unicode regex.

This comes to a surprise to me as well because

```
alert(/\u00B6/.test("¶"));
```

prints true.

Comment: OK. My bad. So what is the correct regular expression to check that a string contains only letters, in every character set? Can this be done?

Comment: The `\uHHHH` notation is a JavaScript *language* feature.  Unicode *regex* support means things like Unicode properties (`\p{L}`), blocks (`\p{InLatinExtendedA}`), and scripts (`\p{Cyrillic}`).  JavaScript regexes have nothing like that; you either have to use the XRegExp Unicode plugin, or switch to a different language.

Comment: For those who may not catch Darin's meaning: He's saying (with a little sarcasm) that Javascript actually *does* (did) have builtin support for unicode regex.